# Define and parameterize a suitable circle $\gamma$ for which the following inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

If $R> 0$ and $R \ne 0$, we are asked to define and parameterize a suitable circle $\gamma$ for which the following inequality is valid
$$\int_\gamma\frac{z+1}{z-1}\mathrm dz\le\frac{2\pi R(r+1)}{R-1}$$

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. I notice that you haven't asked an actual question. I suppose your question might be "How do we do this" or something like that, but I would suggest that you read the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with particular emphasis on how to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) such as: Did you attempt, and fail, to solve this? Can you formulate a mathematical question regarding your attempts?

Comment: If $R>0,$ then $R\ne 0,$ no reason to say the latter. What is $r?$

Comment: Hi, 
r is the radius of the circumference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about a circle centred at the origin. Then you can simply use the residue theorem (or Cauchy's integral formula) to find the **two** possible values the integral can take. This makes it easy to find a general answer.

More simply, you can choose $R<1$ because then, the circle does not enclose the zero at $z=1$ and hence, the integral vanishes.